# How can I detect recursive arrays and hashes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, recursion, hash

How can I detect arrays or hashes that include a recursive structure like `a`, `b`, and `c` below?

- Simplest instance of recursive array

  ```
  a = []
  a[0] = a
  a # => [[...]]
  ```
- Recursion cycle/depth is not one

  ```
  b = [[], :foo]
  b[0][0] = b
  b # => [[[...]], :foo]
  ```
- Recursion at a non-root level

  ```
  c = [a, :foo]
  c # => [[...], :foo]
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I love recursion.

Here's a decent way, iterating through everything and keeping a hash of objects you have seen (for fast lookup)

```
class Object
  def is_recursive?(known = {})
    false
  end
end

module Enumerable
  def is_recursive?(known = {})
    return true if known.include?(self)
    known[self] = true
    begin
      any? do |*args|
        args.any?{|item| item.is_recursive?(known)}
      end
    ensure
      known[self] = false
    end
  end
end

x = []; x << x
p x.is_recursive? # => true
p ({x => 42}).is_recursive? # => true
p [{foo: x}].is_recursive? # => true
p [[[[[[:foo], {bar: [42]}]]]]].is_recursive? # => false
```

Mind you, this is a bit rough and you could run into trouble. For example you'd have endless loops with `[1..Float::INFINITY].is_recursive?`, although that's easily salvable with

```
class Range
  def is_recursive?(known = {})
    false # optimization
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for covering all cases.

Comment: Those Canadians are so smart!

Answer (score 3):

You can't flatten a recursive array, so you could check it by:

```
begin
  a.flatten
rescue ArgumentError => e
  e.to_s =~ /recursive/
end
```

Comment: Great. The error looks like an ArgumentError. So, is recursive array the only cause of `Array#flatten` raising an ArgumentError?

Comment: @sawa I'm not sure, so maybe better only catch the ArgumentError.

Comment: @sawa: The error is raised [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/48d5eb3d406a46beb53069f1060ae385a23a897b/array.c#L4334-4337). Only other way to raise an `ArgumentError` is if any element defines a `to_ary` that somehow raises it.

Comment: @xdazz Your answer was great, but Marc-André Lafortune gave a more general answer, so I am moving the acceptance check. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the method `include?`

```
a = []
a[0] = a
a.include? a
 => true
```

But this don't works for nested arrays, as your second example. You can do this recursivelly:

```
def check_recursive(array, target = nil)
  target ||= array
  return true if array.include?(target)
  array.any? do |obj|
    if obj.kind_of? Array
      check_recursive(obj, target)
      obj.include?(target)
    end
  end
end
```

There are basically two abordages to find it recursive: Look in depth or [deep-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). The best solution depends on your problem. My example implements deep-frist search, which usually it is a good idea.

Comment: This is elegant, but when the recursion is not at the root level, it raises a stackoverflow error. `check_recursive([a, :bar]) # => stackoverflow`.